# cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing crashes with big files

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

My cordova app crashes when it comes to sharing files bigger than 40mb via cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing. With smaller files - fewer images attached - everything is fine. I figured out that if the attachment is about 37mb - everything is fine. One image more - and the total size is above 40 mb - and the app crashes.

Is there a size limit there?
What is a workaround (i am sending array)?
Any other plugin which might be better?

Answer (score 0):

These files were dynamically generated by the app. First I tried to share them right after they were generated. Only small files were shared alright.

Then I solved the issue when I first saved the file to the device storage, and the shared it from the storage (and removed this file after it was shared).

FileSystemService.writeFileToSystem below is name of my service and method, saving the data to the device. After that I get fileEntry object, which I pass to my shareFile function, which takes url from the fileEntry and passes it to the sharing plugin.

```
.then(function(blob){
        return FileSystemService.writeFileToSystem (blob, `${name}` + '.pdf', 'deviceStorageDirectory');
      })
      .then( function(fileEntry) { return shareFile(fileEntry, '.pdf') })
```